# Products exist in the database but are not showing in backend or frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, product, ce-1.9.1.0

In the Magento back-end interface, when viewing Catalog / Manage Products, the list of products is empty.

In addition, in the Magento front-end interface, when viewing any list of products, such as a category, the list of products is empty:

```
http://example.com/category.html
```

However, I am able to view individual products in the front-end interface by typing in the url for the individual product:

```
http://example.com/product.html
```

In addition, I am able to verify that the correct number of products exist in the database using:

```
select count(*) from `catalog_product_entity`;
```

Between when the products were showing and when they disappeared, I had done a System / Import / Dataflow Profiles / Import All Products from a CSV containing data like the following:

```
sku, status
101, enabled
102, disabled
```

The import did not throw any errors, but the status field did not understand the use of enabled / disabled, so I imported again from a CSV containing data like the following:

```
sku, status
101, 1
102, 0
```

Again, the import did not throw any errors, but the values for the status field were still not correct, so after reference to http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-product-csv-files I imported again from a CSV containing data like the following:

```
sku, status
101, 1
102, 2
```

Once again, the import completed without throwing any errors. But even after indexing, none of the products now display in any list of products.

I also tried setting visibility by importing from a CSV containing data like:

```
sku, visibility
101, 4
102, 4
```

Again, the import completed without throwing any errors. But still, none of the products display in any list of products.

**Running System / Import / Dataflow Profiles / Export All Products to CSV shows that the visibility for most records is currently `Catalog / Search` but for the subset of records where visibility was explicitly set to `Catalog / Search` by importing a CSV as above, the visibility is now set to `Not Visible Individually`. It appears that explicitly setting the visibility performs some internal validation that fails and then defaults the visibility to `Not Visible Individually`. What could cause this import validation to fail?**

I believe this is not a duplicate of [Products not showing up in frontend or backend but are enabled and stored correctly in flat table](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6140/products-not-showing-up-in-frontend-or-backend-but-are-enabled-and-stored-correc) because the symptoms of the issue (not displaying in back-end vs not displaying in back-end or front-end) and the versions of Magento (1.5 vs 1.9) are significantly different.

Comment: try http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-fix-the-issue-product-images-missing-in-backend-but-not-in-frontend/ it will surely help if product don't show in admin.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to reproduce the effect. If the status doesn't have the value "1" (enabled) or "2" (disabled), the product doesn't display at all.

You can fix this as follows. Create a PHP file in the base directory named "update_status.php". Paste the following contents:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array(
    array('nin' => array(1,2)),
    array('null' => true)
), 'left');
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $product->addAttributeUpdate('status', 1, 0);
}
```

This will set the status "1" to all products which don't have a correct status. 
Don't forget to delete the file afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Another clue, I did export my product list in another language, so the status name were wrong. Make sure the status is set to Enabled... not in another language in your import file :)